# Graph is connected exactly when it cannot be represented as a union of its two subgraphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

How to prove that a graph is connected exactly when it cannot be represented as a union of its two subgraphs? 
 
 According to one of the definitions, a graph is connected if it cannot be represented as a union of two graphs, and disconnected otherwise. Why is this so, and how can it be formally proven?

Comment: Surely you are missing details and conditions... specifically that the two graphs should be disjoint and non-empty.

Comment: The union of two graphs is clearly disconnected. And if a graph has a connected component $C$ then it is the union of the graphs induced by $C$ and $V\setminus C$. Also, I don't really know what a graph union is, but I'm assuming it is what I think it is.

Comment: Your question should probably also include the definition of "connected" that you're starting with (from which you're trying to prove that this alternate definition is equivalent).

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I think so too. But this is not written in the problem statement. It is said that it is necessary to prove that the graph is connected exactly when it cannot be represented as a union of its two subgraphs. Suppose the graphs are disjoint and non-empty. How is their disconnectivity can be formally proved in this case?

Comment: If you don't have the nonempty condition then note that $G = G\cup \emptyset$... a graph is equal to the union of itself with the empty-graph.  Perhaps you might get around this by having defined a graph as necessarily having at least one vertex and don't consider the empty-graph a graph.  If you don't have the disjoint condition then note that $G = G\cup G$, a graph is equal to the union of itself with itself.

Comment: Now... proving that the statement that a graph cannot be represented as the *disjoint* union of two *non-empty* graphs implies it is connected, see the contrapositive statement that a graph who is disconnected *can* be expressed as the disjoint union of two graphs... To see that, as HereToRelax already pointed out, take one of the graphs to be one of the connected components and the other to be everything else.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Do you mean this definition? "A graph is said to be connected if there is a path between every pair of vertex".

Comment: For the other direction, showing that it is connected implies you can not express as the disjoint union of two nonempty graphs... suppose for contradictory purposes that you could write it as $G = (V_1,E_1)\cup (V_2,E_2)$ with $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$ and $V_1,V_2$ both nonempty.  Let $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$.  As the graph is connected there should be a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$, but such a path would necessarily involve an edge with one end in $V_1$ and the other in $V_2$ and does not exist in $E_1$ and does not exist in $E_2$, a contradiction.